# ANDROID: How do you create an android servlet

Tags: android

I need to know about servlet simulation.

Which programe or software should I install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For android you gotta use eclipse.
Here is a good tutorial http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=288